# Scroll Past UITableViewCell To See New Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**How do I show a video automatically once it has downloaded, without having to scroll past a cell, and scroll back up to see it?**

In a tableview, I have a series of AVPlayer videos.

In each cell (the cellForRowAtIndexPath method), I have the following code to generate an asset for AVPlayer to play

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self getURL:someURLString] options:nil];
```

*getURL*

- if the video is stored locally, it returns the local url
- if the video is stored remotely, it downloads the video data to a
  local url, and then returns the local url

The problem I am having is, that when the video is downloaded, I have to scroll past the cell, and then scroll back up again to see it. (When the video is already stored locally this does not happen)

I have used methods like `setNeedsDisplay` and `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`. But they have not worked.

Thanks for the help! :)

---

Does a UITableViewCell for some reason stall during cellForRowAtIndexPath, in the sense that, when the local URL is returned, it attempts to reach an old version of local URL (before the cellForRowAtIndexPath was called)? (just a wild guess?)

---

Temporary Solution:

**Can you suggest a better way to download video (each video is only around 200KB) than in cellForRowAtIndexPath since this does not seem to be working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get a reference to the UITableViewCell object and change its Content, etc.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hey, I've changed!";
```

Comment: I tried this, it does not work unfortunately, I think the problem has something to do with the cell not taking into account that the url has new data, but I am not sure. I appreciate the attempt though. :)

Comment: can't you reload whole table again?

Comment: I guess that works, although the flash of the cell's videos that have already loaded, is fairly annoying

Comment: one thing that i want to suggest you that pass the cell to method that downloading video when table is loading cell. so that you have the reference of cell in that method so that you can update that cell directly from that method.

Comment: Can't say exactly. but i think AVPlayer not initialized properly. have you add avplayeritem using [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem]; ???

Comment: Actually it was just a debugging error, I was checkign it too early, it is properly initialized, this is so so confusing, thanks for helping out, one thing I do not understand is reloadRowForIndexPath does not work but reloadData does? Thanks once again @ArmaanStranger

Comment: You are Most Welcome my friend. just do one thing. if its helped you then you can upvote and accept answer as solved.

Comment: This did not exactly solve the problem, but it got me on the right track. Thanks! @ArmaanStranger